# Not Posting to Sphinx, Using Form, unable to pass instance to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx, gmaps4rails

I am current working on a recycling application using the gem google-maps-for-rails to display a map with trash bins/recycling bins locations etc. I have a trash.rb model with name and address as attributes. The gem allows you to take the attributes namely the address and convert that into markers and lat/longitude on the map.

I am trying to implement a sphinx feature, lets say a user wants to recycle 'papers' - this would be under my category column in my table. I indexed the category column. My hope is that when the user post 'paper', only the address with that same category will have its marker displayed on the map.

Everything got indexed correctly. I am not getting any errors but nothing is happening.

I am having trouble passing the current instance to the form ? I am editing this after thinking about this last night.

Here is my trashes_controller.rb, just focused on the index method

```
class TrashesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /trashes
  # GET /trashes.json


  def index
    @trashes = Trash.search(params[:search])
    end
  end


  # GET /trashes/1
  # GET /trashes/1.json
  def show
    @trash = Trash.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trash }
    end
  end

  # GET /trashes/new
  # GET /trashes/new.json
  def new
    @trash = Trash.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trash }
    end
  end

  # GET /trashes/1/edit
  def edit
    @trash = Trash.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /trashes
  # POST /trashes.json
  def create
    @trash = Trash.new(params[:trash])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @trash.save
        format.html { redirect_to @trash, notice: 'Trash was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @trash, status: :created, location: @trash }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @trash.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /trashes/1
  # PUT /trashes/1.json
  def update
    @trash = Trash.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @trash.update_attributes(params[:trash])
        format.html { redirect_to @trash, notice: 'Trash was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @trash.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /trashes/1
  # DELETE /trashes/1.json
  def destroy
    @trash = Trash.find(params[:id])
    @trash.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to trashes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

trash.rb model

```
class Trash < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name, :category,

  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
     "#{address}"
  end 

  def gmaps4rails_infowindow
    "#{self.address}"
  end 
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Boston/Cambridge trash bin locations</h1>
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @trashes.each do |trash| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= trash.name %></td>
    <td><%= trash.address %></td>
    <td><%= trash.category %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_trash_path(trash) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', trash, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Boston Solar Powered Trash Can Location', new_trash_path %>

<%= form_tag trashes_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have changed my index.html.erb to this for testing the sphinx feature.

```
<%= link_to 'New Boston Solar Powered Trash Can Location', new_trash_path %>

<%= form_tag trashes_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It is searching, I used rails console, and can search against the model. However it isn't displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `@trashes` instance variable in your view, but the search results are in the `@searchtrashes` instance variable. You will need to use that instead of you want the displayed objects to reflect the search term.

Comment: it isn't working for me. my index method only has one instance `@trashes = Trash.search(params[:search])` with the the same form_tag from above. I figured the form can find the instance since there is only one, but its still not displaying the search.

Comment: What's the output in your Rails log when you submit the form?

Comment: `Started GET "/trashes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=trash+&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-18 14:21:19 -0400
Processing by TrashesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"trash ", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendered trashes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 52.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)` is processing correctly but not displaying the result.

Comment: I'd expect to see the search call and underlying ActiveRecord call in the logs, so yes, something's not working. I'm not sure what though... hard to debug here.